# Getting logged in User's Profile in Django without repeating request.user a lot?

Tags: python, django

The application I am writing in Django requires me to get a UserProfile model object (which has a one-to-one relationship with the standard Django User object) in a lot of the views. To get the user's profile, I end up repeating something like this quite a bit in all the different views:

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

or

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

I know good software engineering principles say don't repeat yourself (DRY), so I was wondering if there was a good way to encapsulate the code above in a separate method or if it's fine to keep it the way it is.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) to your UserProfile in `models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    about = models.TextField(default='')
```

Then in your `views.py`, reference it with

```
request.user.profile.about = 'abc'
request.user.profile.save()
```

Or make it shorter

```
p = request.user.profile
p.about = 'abc'
p.save()
```

Comment: Just tried this out and it worked wonderfully. Thank you for the answer, it was exactly what I was looking for!